# Display post of Author Posts only (exclude admin and editor ) in archive

Tags: wordpress

My default code is displaying all post of Admins,Editors and Authors. But I only want to show the post of Authors.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php
        if( have_posts() ):
            while( have_posts() ): the_post();
                the_title();
                the_content();
            endwhile;
        endif;
    ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: do you want to display current user post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This one.

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ):

    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();
    $author_query = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'author' => $current_user->ID
    );

    $author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
    while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>       
    <?php endwhile;

else :

    // Do Something

endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $query = new WP_Query( array( 'author__not_in' => array( 1, 2 ) ) ); //Replace id 2 or 6 with your admin and editor user id
```

- **author__in** (array) – use author id (available since version 3.7).(include id for specific author id post)
- **author__not_in** (array) – use author id (available since version 3.7).(exclude the id)

For you better understanding please review this [article](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#author-parameters)